# Complexity of a Chess Knight game

Tags: c, time-complexity, backtracking

I'm having issues understanding Asymptotic Analysis or Complexity, I tried the following [link](https://philipstel.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/determining-the-complexity-of-an-algorithm-the-basic-part/)
and read the complete article, this however didn't give me final answer to my question, which is:

**Am I supposed to write complexity for each line of code and sum them up or something else?** My teacher didn't quite explained how to do it but wants it done.

> Condition: a knight (chess) must cross an iced-lake (m x **n** matrix) and get his buddy
>   from the other side of the lake with given obstacles. Every time he
>   jumps, the cell of the matrix that he jumps on becomes an obstacle
>   (ice falls). After he gets his buddy he must return to the starting
>   point following a different route. Starting point is bottom corner left cell, his buddy is located on top right corner cell

I used Backtracking for this algorithm and the problem that remains is calculating **time** or **asymptotic complexity**.
Code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define N 50
typedef struct{
   int x;
   int y;
} coordonate;
int sol=0,m,n;
coordonate vectSol[N];
void jump(int xL,int yL,int xD,int yD,int obstacole[N][N],int steps,coordonate road[N]);
int main(){
    int i,j,x,y,obstacole[N][N],nrObs;
    int KnightMatrixRoad[N][N], KnightMatrixBack[N][N];
    coordonate pathKnight[N],pathBack[N];
    printf("m=");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Nr. of obstacles: ");
    scanf("%d",&nrObs);
    for(i=0;i<nrObs;i++){
        printf("Insert obstacle %d through space bar (x,y):",i+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        obstacole[y-1][x-1]=1;
    }
    jump(0,0,m-1,n-1,obstacole,0,pathKnight);
    for(i=0;i<=sol;i++){
        obstacole[vectSol[i].y][vectSol[i].x]=1;
        pathKnight[i]=vectSol[i];
        vectSol[i].x=0;
        vectSol[i].y=0;
    }
    sol=obstacole[n-1][m-1]=obstacole[0][0]=0;
    jump(m-1,n-1,0,0,obstacole,0,pathBack);
    for(i=0;i<=sol;i++){
        pathBack[i]=vectSol[i];
        vectSol[i].x=0;
        vectSol[i].y=0;
    }
    for(i=0;(pathKnight[i-1].x!=m-1) || (pathKnight[i-1].y!=n-1);i++){
        KnightMatrixRoad[pathKnight[i].y][pathKnight[i].x]=i;
    }
    puts("\nPath to his buddy:\n");
    for(i=n-1,sol=0;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            printf("%3d",KnightMatrixRoad[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    for(i=0;((pathBack[i-1].x!=0) || (pathBack[i-1].y!=0)) || i==0;i++){
        KnightMatrixBack[pathBack[i].y][pathBack[i].x]=i;
    }
    puts("\nPath back to starting point:\n");
    for(i=n-1,sol=0;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            printf("%3d",KnightMatrixBack[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    getch();
}
void jump(int xLocal,int yLocal,int xDest,int yDest,int obstacole[N][N],int steps,coordonate road[N]){
    int i,j;
    int tempObstacole[N][N];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            tempObstacole[i][j]=obstacole[i][j];
        }
    road[steps].x=xLocal;
    road[steps].y=yLocal;
    if(xLocal==xDest && yLocal==yDest){
        if(sol==0 || steps<sol){
            for(i=0;i<=sol;i++){
                vectSol[i].x=0;
                vectSol[i].y=0;
            }
            sol=steps;
            for(i=0;i<=sol;i++)
                vectSol[i]=road[i];
        }
    }
    if(sol==0 || steps+1<sol){
        tempObstacole[yLocal][xLocal]=1;
        if(yLocal+2<n && xLocal+1<m && !(tempObstacole[yLocal+2][xLocal+1]))
            jump(xLocal+1,yLocal+2,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal+2<n && xLocal-1>=0 && !(tempObstacole[yLocal+2][xLocal-1]))
            jump(xLocal-1,yLocal+2,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal-2>=0 && xLocal+1<m && !(tempObstacole[yLocal-2][xLocal+1]))
            jump(xLocal+1,yLocal-2,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal-2>=0 && xLocal-1>=0 && !(tempObstacole[yLocal-2][xLocal-1]))
            jump(xLocal-1,yLocal-2,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal+1<n && xLocal+2<m && !(tempObstacole[yLocal+1][xLocal+2]))
            jump(xLocal+2,yLocal+1,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal+1<n && xLocal-2>=0 && !(tempObstacole[yLocal+1][xLocal-2]))
            jump(xLocal-2,yLocal+1,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal-1>=0 && xLocal+2<m && !(tempObstacole[yLocal-1][xLocal+2]))
            jump(xLocal+2,yLocal-1,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
        if(yLocal-1>=0 && xLocal-2>=0 && !(tempObstacole[yLocal-1][xLocal-2]))
            jump(xLocal-2,yLocal-1,xDest,yDest,tempObstacole,steps+1,road);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're analyzing  code, you have to analyse it line by line, counting every operation/recognizing time complexity, in the end, you have to sum it to get whole picture.

For example, you can have one simple loop with *linear complexity*, but later in that same program you can have a triple loop that has *cubic complexity*, so your program will have **cubic complexity**. Function order of growth comes into play right here.

Let's look at what are possibilities for time complexity of an algorithm, you can see order of growth I mentioned above:

- *Constant time* has an order of growth `1`, for example: `a = b + c`.
- *Logarithmic time* has an order of growth `LogN`, it usually occurs
  when you're dividing something in half (binary search, trees, even loops), or multiplying something in same way.
- *Linear*, order of growth is `N`, for example

  ```
  int p = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    p = p + 2;
  ```
- *Linearithmic*, order of growth is `n*logN`, usually occurs in divide and conquer algorithms.
- *Cubic*, order of growth `N^3`, classic example is a triple loop where you check all triplets:

  ```
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            x = x + 2
  ```
- *Exponential*, order of growth `2^N`, usually occurs when you do exhasutive search, for example check subsets of some set.

I think that your teacher wanted to get whole picture where you'll figure out that backtracking algorithms are very very slow.

Comment: If I understood corectly, complexity for a section from the program will be:
    for(i=0;i<nrObs;i++){ // [1+2n +2n] //
        printf("Insert obstacle %d through space bar (x,y):",i+1); // [1+2n] //
        obstacole[y-1][x-1]=1; // [2n] //
    }
And I have to this for the entire program?

Comment: Yes, you will have to find complexity for each loop/each part of code that is not constant, sum it up and in the end, time complexity is one with biggest order of growth.